# unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR

Tags: php

I am receiving an error with this code. I am new to PHP but it is my understanding that `||` is translated to 'OR'. I am trying to check if the uploaded file meets any of the three conditions, and if so set an error.

```
if ($uploaded_size > 1048576) || 
   ($uploaded_type == 'application/octet-stream') || 
   (file_exists($target))
{ 
    echo "Error: File was not uploaded.<br>"; 
    $ok=0; 
}
```

The error states that "unexpected T_BOOLEAN_OR"

Comment: Wow, I can't believe all the down voting. Care to explain?

Comment: On Stackoverflow.com, we don't generally like PHP errors that are obvious syntax errors and can easily be solved by reading the manual. It seems that you have misunderstood the `if`-construct. The if-construct looks like `if (   ...condition.... )`, not `if  ...condition...`

Comment: If you cant solve such errors by yourself then you either 1) don't have enough understanding of the language yet or 2) you didn't even spend 2 minutes on it before coming here...

Comment: @Lekensteyn I can understand this. The problem was my misunderstanding of how the IF statement worked.

Comment: Which isn't to say that this is necessarily a bad question -- StackOverflow's goal is to have answers to questions, even if they could be found with Google. I think this is an ok question, since you included the code and the error message, and "unexpected X" error messages aren't exactly human readable -- you just get used to them after a while. Anyway, don't take the downvotes too seriously. I have a bunch of them and it's not exactly hurting my score.

Comment: @BrendanLong Thanks. It was surprising to see all the down votes right away! But I can understand how someone who looks at PHP code day in and day out would look at this as a very simple problem.

Comment: Well, it is a valid question, true. I still don't think it belongs on Stackoverflow. We could flood the whole site with such errors (you can trigger this specific one in multiple ways). Checking for syntax errors before you come here is just common sense. If you google the error you get the general idea that its a syntax error and how to solve it... It just makes people lazy IMO. -- But this is just me, maybe I'm just grumpy. I didn't have SO "in my day". Hah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ($uploaded_size > 1048576) ||
```

Notice that you end the `if` statement with a `)` before the `||`, so the `||` is just sitting outside by itself. You're also missing a parenthesis between `(file_exists($target))`
 and the `{`.

You probably want this:

```
if (($uploaded_size > 1048576) || 
    ($uploaded_type == 'application/octet-stream') || 
    (file_exists($target)))
{
```

Or the equivalent:

```
if ($uploaded_size > 1048576 || 
    $uploaded_type == 'application/octet-stream' || 
    file_exists($target))
{
```